# What's websockets and what js framework should I use

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, websocket

I'm very new to the Java Script world , I use Laravel already for my backend but when it came to the websockets part I kinda got messy , because when I looked for websockets I have read that they all are depending on Node JS for real time apps like chat apps but also I have seen a tutorial making a chat app in Vue Js & laravel echo only without using node js ,

now the messy part for me is , If I want to learn socket.io  (for example) should I learn Node Js  first ? And is Vue js an alternative for the socketio ? 
and How about the ajax ? isn't it able to do the same performance ?

I'm sorry but It's kinda messy for me , I have looked for that but it is still messy for me , thanks for advance

Comment: Hey! This isn't the right forum for this question. This isn't really the right place to ask for recommendations (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I would suggest that you take this question over to the javascript subreddit and ask there (https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript)

Comment: Sure , Thanks  !

Comment: http://dodo.mikosoft.info - The Dodo as an easy framework for beginners. Blazing fast, easy to learn, Javascript, frontend framework for reactive web pages & apps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I want to learn socket.io (for example) should I learn Node Js first?

Yes. Since *Socket.IO* is a Node.js package, it's kind of a pre-requisite to learn Node. It's one of the easiest tools to learn though, so don't be intimidated.

> And is Vue js an alternative for the socketio?

No. Vue.js is front-end framework, which means it's used to build the part of the website you actually see. Socket.io is a package (or framework) that enables bi-directional communication between the front-end and the back-end of your application. You can use it for example to build a chat application.

> How about the ajax ? isn't it able to do the same performance?

No. Ajax is short for *Asynchronous JavaScript And XML*. Which basically means that you use Ajax requests from the front-end to the back-end. The difference here is that Websockets/Socket.IO gives you the bi-directional communication that Ajax lacks. You don't need Socket.IO for all communication though

Comment: Thanks Max, much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks a lot  , but If Vue.js is not an alternative , how had he built a chatapp only using it ? without even using socet.io or anything else ? and it is working good , Could you please explain this , and thanks again!

Comment: Who is he? And to answer your question, you can use other technologies similar to Socket.IO. For example you have [gRPC](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web). Another commercial tool is [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com) which you can use for real-time stuff

Comment: this is the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5sXmfwnxfjA&list=PLJpBh2VJhy5x2GKfkfIcn0r6P6uLat7xR he was using axios but is it similar to socket io ??

Comment: No `axios` is for HTTP requests (Ajax calls), it's not bi-directional like Socket.io

Comment: really nice descriptive answer +1

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everything exposed in the accepted answer except that Vuejs isn't an alternative. It is true that vuejs is a javascript framework to create frontends, but, if you have a nodejs server with a socketio server, you need a client (frontend) which must be able to communicate through socketio. You can see this by yourself [here](https://github.com/probil/vue-socket.io-extended), this is one of the most common vue wrappers library to use socketio from vuejs. I hope this could help